# Binding the textbox width of a ComboBox to the width of its parent ComboBox in Window.Resources (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp-xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I designed a custom `ComboBox`.

I'd like to bind my `ComboBox's textbox width` to the width of its parent `ComboBox`.

For example, if the width of the `ComboBox` changes in `Grid.Children`, its `TextBox` should likewise change.

[image: custom ComboBox]

`XAML:`

Note: Some unnecessary blocks have been removed for readability and convenience.

Note: I'm aware that the `PART EditableTextBox` section needs to be edited, but I'm not sure how.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF888888" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                     Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     Focusable="false"
                     ClickMode="Press"
                     IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                             IsHitTestVisible="False"
                             Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                             ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                             ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                             Margin="3,3,23,3"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                    Style="{x:Null}"
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                    Focusable="True"
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Visibility="Hidden"
                    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                  Placement="Bottom"
                  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                  AllowsTransparency="True"
                  Focusable="False"
                  PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                   MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer BorderBrush="DarkGray" Padding="3,3,3,11" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="9" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" >
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border CornerRadius="0,9,9,0" Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarNormalBackground}" Width="15" Margin="2,2,0,0"  BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track"  IsDirectionReversed="True" Uid="PART_Track">
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Uid="Thumb_0">
                                            <Thumb.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Width="15" Height="12" Margin="2,2,0,0" CornerRadius="0,9,9,0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Cursor="Hand" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Thumb.Template>
                                        </Thumb>
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                </Track>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="9" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFC5CBF9" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFDDDDDD" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Children>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Category_ComboBox" GotFocus="Category_ComboBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="Category_ComboBox_LostFocus" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CustomContextMenu}" IsEditable="True" BorderBrush="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" Margin="21,138,0,0"/>
    </Grid.Children>
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box `PART_EditableTextBox` is only visible when the `ComboBox` is in edit mode (which is when `ComboBox.IsEdit` is enabled).
To make it stretch simply set the `TextBox.HorizontalAlignment` property to `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

In case you meant to make the items in the selection box to stretch set `ComboBox.HorizontalContentAlignment` to `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`:

```xml
<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```